# How to debug the Networkmanager-dispatcher-variables

Tags: network-manager

I want to debug a script that contain Networkmanager-Dispacher-Variables like `DEVICE_IFACE`, `IP4_GATEWAY`. I need to get the values of these variables. The Networkmanager-manual describes these variables but doesn't mention how to debug them.

I searched a lot but i am unable to figure out how to do that. When i echo on the command line like `echo ${DEVICE_IFACE}` i get no value.